# How to reduce the equation？

Tags: simplifying-expressions

[image]
[image]

```
Factor[Det[{{x, y, z}, {z, x, y}, {y, z, x}}], 
 Extension -> {(-1 + Sqrt[-3])/2, I}]
```

How can I simplify this expression as in the first picture? In my second picture, you can see that this does not succeed.

Comment: `Det[{{x,y,z},{z,x,y},{y,z,x}}]==x^3+y^3-3*x*y*z+z^3` but `(x+y+z)*(x^2+w*y+w^2*z)* (x^2+w^2*y+w*z)/.w->(-1+Sqrt[-3])/2//Expand==x^5-x^3*y+x^4*y+x*y^2-x^2*y^2+y^3-x^3*z+x^4*z-x*y*z-2*x^2*y*z+x*z^2-x^2*z^2+z^3` Is there some mistake in your first picture?

Comment: As Bill has pointed out, I think there is an error in the equation you give in the first picture.  You  want to get the determinant in the form `(x+y+z)(x +w y + w^2 z) (x + w^2 y + w z)` _not_  `(x+y+z)(x^2 +w y + w^2 z) (x^2 + w^2 y + w z)`.  (Have a look at the equation circled in black in the second picture). As far as I can see, the value for omega is correct, and note that `w + w^2 = -1`

Comment: @ 比尔@tomd Yes.I write it wrongly.Thank your.

Comment: @我心永恒 You already have asked 3 questions on our site. Before you ask your next question, please consider reading how you can [format your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) so that it is readable by using correct markdown. It doesn't matter that you are not an English native speaker, but putting a whitespace after each period, comma or question mark can still be done. Finally, we don't end questions here with "Thank you". We simply ask and show our appreciation of answers by upvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
det = Det[{{x, y, z}, {z, x, y}, {y, z, x}}];

(w^2 == ((-1 + Sqrt[-3])/2)^2 // Simplify)

(* 1 + I Sqrt[3] + 2 w^2 == 0 *)
```

Consequently,

```
rule = Sqrt[3] -> -(2 w^2 + 1)/I;

expr1 = Factor[det, Extension -> {(-1 + Sqrt[-3])/2, I}] /. rule // Simplify

(* (x + w^2 (y - z) - z) (x + y + z) (x - (1 + w^2) y + w^2 z) *)
```

Or,

```
expr2 = Collect[#, z] & /@ expr1

(* (x + y + z) (x - (1 + w^2) y + w^2 z) (x + w^2 y + (-1 - w^2) z) *)
```

Verifying that `expr1` and `expr2` are equal to `det`

```
(det == expr1 == expr2 /. w -> (-1 + Sqrt[-3])/2) // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
myDet = Det[{{x, y, z}, {z, x, y}, {y, z, x}}];
```

(i)

```
myDet == (Factor[myDet, Extension -> { (-1 + Sqrt[-3])/2, I}] // Simplify) 
  == (Factor[(x + y + z) (x + w y + w^2 z) (x + w^2 y + w z) /. w :>  (-1 + Sqrt[-3])/2] 
  // Simplify)
```

> True

(ii)

```
myDet == ((x + y + z) (  
  x + ((-I + Sqrt[3]) y)/(2 I) + ((-I + Sqrt[3]) /(2 I))^2 z) (  
  x + ((-I + Sqrt[3]) /(2 I))^2 y + ((-I + Sqrt[3]) /(2 I)) z) // 
Factor // Simplify)
```

> True

The last part of (ii), as Latex:

$\text{Factor}\left[(x+y+z) \left(x+\frac{\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right) y}{2 i}+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2 i}\right)^2 z\right) \left(x+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2 i}\right)^2 y+\frac{\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right) z}{2 i}\right)\right]$

in the desired form of

$$(x+y+z) \left(x+y \omega +\omega ^2 z\right) \left(x+y \omega ^2+\omega  z\right)$$

(iii) Relationships

```
(-1 + Sqrt[-3])/2 + ((-1 + Sqrt[-3])/2)^2 // Simplify
```

> -1

```
(-I + Sqrt[3]) /(2 I) == ((-1 + Sqrt[-3])/2)^2 // Simplify
```

> True

Comment: thank your help。nice。